# pandas correlation matrix between each pair groupby item

Tags: python, pandas, correlation

I have a csv file like this:

```
date,sym,close
2014.01.01,A,10
2014.01.02,A,11
2014.01.03,A,12
2014.01.04,A,13
2014.01.01,B,20
2014.01.02,B,22
2014.01.03,B,23
2014.01.01,C,33
2014.01.02,C,32
2014.01.03,C,31
```

Then, I get a dateframe named `df` via `read_csv` function

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('daily.csv',index_col=[0])
groups=df.groupby('sym')[['close']].apply(lambda x:func(x['close'].values))
```

The `groups` look like this:

```
sym
A    [nan,1.00,2.00,...]
B    [nan,1.00,2.00,...]
C    [nan,1.00,2.00,...]
```

How to calculate the correlation between each pair of sym?

```
AA,AB,AC,BB,BA,BC,CA,CB,CC
```

BTW, the item numbers of each sym may be **NOT** the same.

Comment: Sounds like you just want numpy ```corrcoef()```.  If that's not enough, it would be helpful to also post a small sample dataset (with differing numbers of items) along with your code.

Comment: @JohnE I have added a sample dataset :)

Comment: The numbers of sym are about 20.

Comment: Your sample data probably needs to be amended to have different dates for each 'sym' (e.g. 2014.01.01,A,10, 2014.01.02,A,10, 2014.01.03,A,10)

Comment: @Alexander you're right. I have changed dates.

Answer (score 16):

With `df` as above,  make a pivot table:

```
dfp = df.pivot('date','sym')
print(dfp)
```

> ```
>            close        
> sym            A   B   C
> date                    
> 2014-01-01    10  20  33
> 2014-01-02    11  22  32
> 2014-01-03    12  23  31
> 2014-01-04    13 NaN  30
> ```

pandas will calculate the pairwise coefficients:

```
print(dfp.corr())
```

> ```
>               close                    
> sym               A         B         C
>       sym                              
> close A    1.000000  0.981981 -1.000000
>       B    0.981981  1.000000 -0.981981
>       C   -1.000000 -0.981981  1.000000
> ```

But if you want to prettify it, check out `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.corrplot(dfp, annot=True)
```

result:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

After get `groups`:

```
sym
A    [nan,1.00,2.00,...]
B    [nan,1.00,2.00,...]
C    [nan,1.00,2.00,...]
```

I created a DataFrame df2

```
df2=DataFrame()
df2['A']=groups['A']
df2['B']=groups['B']
df2['C']=groups['C']

df2.corr()
```

This method can get the correlation via data of groups. However, not perfect.
How to convert a groups to a DataFrame like this? Loop keys of groups? I need to continue to try.